# Cron SyntaxError with Selenium Python Script

Tags: python, selenium, cron

I'm a beginner trying to write a small Python script that I will run through Cron, but I'm getting a Syntax Error from my Cron output log about the program, although the script works fine running through Terminal.

```
  File "/home/pi/Selenium.py", line 19
    clickinput = driver.find_element_by_link_text(f"{date}- File")
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried looking up how to do this, and one person with a similar issue changed Cron to run as Bash instead of sh, but when I added SHELL = /bin/bash to the Cron file, nothing happened, and I got the same error. Additionally, when I change the f-string into a non f-string, a "selenium module not found" error gets thrown instead.

Any help figuring out the cause of the error would be appreciated!

Cron command:

```
PATH = /home/pi/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/s$
SHELL = /bin/bash
20 18 * * * /home/pi/Selenium.py > /home/pi/Desktop/backdown.log 2>&1
20 18 * * * env > /home/pi/Desktop/env.output 2>&1
```

Here is my Python script (minus private info)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")
driver.get("website");

searchinput = driver.find_element_by_name('mail')
searchinput.send_keys("email")
searchinput = driver.find_element_by_name("pass")
searchinput.send_keys("password")
searchinput.submit()

date = datetime.today().strftime("%m/%d")
if date.find("0") == 0:
    date = date.lstrip("0")
    
clickinput = driver.find_element_by_link_text(f"{date}- File")
clickinput.click()
```

(This is my first time posting, so sorry if it's bad)

Comment: I'm guessing `env` under `cron` finds an older Python which doesn't support `f"string"` syntax. Can you add a separate cron job with just `/usr/bin/env python --version >>output 2>&1` and check what it writes to the file?

Comment: But running graphical programs from `cron` is not going to work without additional hacks. Selenium (without something like Xvfb) requires access to your `DISPLAY` which of course in turn doesn't exist if you don't have a graphical desktop running.

Comment: @tripleee should I try running it as headless? The output log said 2.7.16, which I guess doesn't support f-string?

Comment: Yup, f-strings are only available in relatively recent Python 3 versions. Try `env python3` instead maybe?

Comment: And yes, headless woud be the way to go if you don't expect to have a live graphical desktop open at all times (and probably a good idea even if you do, as I guess it could interfere with interactive use).

Comment: @tripleee The output said python 3.7.3. Would there be a command to run that version? And thank you for your help so far!

Comment: You already found that command. Just change the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env python3`